# Microsoft graph convert content endpoint fails when calling from client side

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am calling GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content?format=pdf endpoint to get the file content in PDF format. The call returns with a status 302 and a location header. if we do get call on this location from our web app, it fails during the options call with a status of 404.

Here is the request we are doing to get the pdf contents.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!gsJ9tz6DCkGyfdaU5v6ixyaFWxnS3xFCqH4I1SLV8CdtgB6dTj-DS6PTgkh_en6V/items/017JOTXVHOWSIA4OPTEND3H2D55XXSKVVG/content?format=pdf

It returns this [URL](https://westeurope1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/pdf?provider=spo&inputFormat=xlsx&cs=YzU3NDRjMGItYzhhMi00YjAwLTgxOTUtY2I0MWQzOWJlYmVifFNQTw&correlationId=0509289d-060c-4d85-9348-9a1a43cc8c9c&docid=https:%2F%2Ffigg.sharepoint.com%2F_api%2Fv2.0%2Fdrives%2Fb!gsJ9tz6DCkGyfdaU5v6ixyaFWxnS3xFCqH4I1SLV8CdtgB6dTj-DS6PTgkh_en6V%2Fitems%2F017JOTXVHOWSIA4OPTEND3H2D55XXSKVVG%3Ftempauth%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.bzZKdG94TnZBREFBN2FoUWNYUEU0Z2RmVnFsZ1ExOGozMjhTYVU0b0VrVT0%26version%3DPublished) in location header. The url if I open directly in browser works fine and I am able to download the pdf. But if I do a get call with JS it fails on options call with 404.
[image]

It looks like CORS is not correctly supported for this endpoint. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.